# Twilio Showing Wrong Number of Segments

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am calling Twilio API to fetch messages history. The number of messages and segments returned by the API are different than it shows in the Twilio Usage section. The end point I am calling to fetch the messages list is:
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/Account_SID/Messages.json

Please see the stats returned by Usage API for April 14, 2021 in the screenshot below:
[image]

You can see in the screenshot that the number of messages returned are 685 while the messages API is returning only 561 messages. Why is there such discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

The difference has to do with message segments. The /Messages resources and has a field called,  "num_segments": "X" - so one message may be made up of multiple segments.

/Messages will be less than the result of the Usage API if you sent a message with more than one [segment](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/what-the-heck-is-a-segment.html). A segment is what you are charged for. You can use this tool to see how many segments a message has, or view the results using the field mentioned above, `num_segments`.

[Message Segment Tool](https://twiliodeved.github.io/message-segment-calculator/)

Comment: HI Alan. Thanks for your reply. Messages and Segments both numbers are different when I calculate through Messages API and when I make a call to the Usage API. I can't figure out what could possibly be missing as I am not manually doing anything both results are coming from Twilio API.

Comment: My recommendation is to divide your reconciliation into smaller date frames of data, to see where they start to diverge. You an do this both with the Messages and Usage resources. Let us know what you find.